# installing netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: installation, java, netbeans

I get following error
 /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_25/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXtst.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Installation stops there.
I checked and in the directory mentioned there is no file like libXtst.so.6 . The Java ( oracle ) installation is from latest download. java version and javac version gives the required outputs.

Comment: Are you running your ubuntu with an Xserver?

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur if /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_25 is the 32 bit (i586) version and the application calling it requires the 64 bit version of the JDK.

Comment: So... Then how to fix this? As it currently stands it's more a comment rather than an answer.